# How does InnoDB store tables in ibdata file?

Tags: mysql, innodb, ibdata, btree

There are two tables and their default engine is InnoDB.

I want know the following

- What's inside the ibdata file ?
- How does InnoDB store these two tables ?

Comment: You should have used Google first. http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/03/the-basics-of-innodb-space-file-layout/, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/innodb-table-and-index.html#innodb-physical-structure

Answer (score 2):

## InnoDB Architecture

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Percona created this picture a long time ago. As you can see, ibdata1 contains many classes of data structures. There are as follows:

- Table Data Pages (if [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled)
- Table Index Pages (if [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled)
- Data Dictionary (Tablespace IDs, Logical-to-Physical Mapping to Tables)
- Double Write Buffer (Handles Data Redundancy to Support Crash Recovery)
- Insert Buffer (Handles Updates to Secondary Indexes)
- Rollback Segments (Manages Reverse Engineering of Uncommitted Transactions)
- Undo Space (Containers of Information for Rollback Operations)

## BTREEs in InnoDB

If you are concerned how indexes are stored, please read my earlier posts about InnoDB indexes

- `Apr 04, 2012` : [How does innodb_stats_on_metadata relate to query execution plan stability?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16094/how-does-innodb-stats-on-metadata-relate-to-query-execution-plan-stability/16095#16095)
- `Jun 28, 2012` : [Benefits of BTREE in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20047/benefits-of-btree-in-mysql/20114#20114)
- `Oct 26, 2012` : [How badly does innodb fragment in the face of somewhat out-of-order insertions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27678/how-badly-does-innodb-fragment-in-the-face-of-somewhat-out-of-order-insertions/27685#27685)
- `Jan 09, 2013` : [Is ANALYZE useful immediately after creating an InnoDB index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56416/is-analyze-useful-immediately-after-creating-an-innodb-index/56480#56480)
- `Mar 27, 2013` : [Are there implicit indexes in InnoDB like MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37643/are-there-implicit-indexes-in-innodb-like-myisam/38690#38690)
- `Jun 14, 2013` : [Does the size of the primary key contribute to table size?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44520/does-the-size-of-the-primary-key-contribute-to-table-size/44553#44553)